# Change Fomula before typesetting MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Suppose, I have many formulae on the page.

I want to enclose each formula in `\large{}`, i.e. `$x+1$` becomes `$\large{x+1}$`.

Is there any way I can do this with MathJax or I need to set skipstartup to true, manually add and then queue typeset?

Is there any way MathJax could fetch those formulae?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use `prefilter`:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/MXqOpqPeBF4/h-hry2ITzz4J

```
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
        MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () { 
          MathJax.InputJax.TeX.prefilterHooks.Add(function (data) { 
            data.math = '\\large{'+data.math+'}'; 
          }); 
        }); 
  </script>
```