# Automatic macro substitution on an HTML page before MathJax processes it

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm using LaTeX for many years, but I'm new in MathJax and JavaScript.

I have the following question. Suppose I'm going to use my own macro (let us name it mycommand), so I'll place it in my MathJax config (in the Macros section). I want to use this command everywhere on my HTML pages between the Math delimiters (i.e., `\( ... \)`, `$ ... $`, `\[ ... \]`, `$$ ... $$`), where any string that matches my (fixed) regular expression `RE` (for example, let us suppose that this regexp is `\d+`) is appearing. I mean the following: where any string `STR` that matches this `RE` is appearing between the Math delimiters, there this substitution `STR -> \mycommand{STR}` must be applied automatically, i.e., if we have, for example, in an HTML source something like that:

```
\(foo STR0 bar\)
...
$foo STR1 bar$
...
\[
foo STR2 bar
\]
...
$$foo STR3 bar STR4 baz$$
```

(where `STR0`, `STR1`, `STR2`, `STR3`, `STR4` all match my regexp `RE`), then before MathJax processes these Math expressions, these ones must be preprocessed automatically to the following:

```
\(foo \mycommand{STR0} bar\)
...
$foo \mycommand{STR1} bar$
...
\[
foo \mycommand{STR2} bar
\]
...
$$foo \mycommand{STR3} bar \mycommand{STR4} baz$$
```

This substitution should be done automatically, in a browser, not manually or with any editing software.

Is it possible to do this with MathJax (maybe plus JavaScript)? If yes, how this could be done?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [TeX macros](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros)?

Comment: @Peter Krautzberger Yes. And I have created my own macro. And I need not only that but an automatic substitution of my macro everywhere on an HTML page by my regexp.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I can't see any option to do this substitution with a macro itself. Al least, I have found nothing about that in the documentation on TeX macros.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm afraid it's not possible to do get that kind of substitution from MathJax; it converts TeX input into an internal data structure similar to MathML.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I have found these questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210529/change-fomula-before-typesetting-mathjax) and [two](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/MXqOpqPeBF4/h-hry2ITzz4J), but I don't know how to adapt their answers to my case (replace with regexp). It should be like this offline solution with sed: `sed -r s'/([[:digit:]]+)/\\mycommand{\1}/g'`

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I have found how to do that: `data.math = data.math.replace(/(RE)/g, "\\mycommand{$1}");` It works. Your [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/MXqOpqPeBF4/h-hry2ITzz4J) does help me (with an additional googling) to find this solution.